# iOS 9 Bundle requires launch storyboard for iPad Support

Tags: ios, xcode

Whenever I try to submit my app to the app store using Xcode 7, I get the following message from the application launcher.
[image]

Im wondering how to add a launch storyboard and if its any different then a normal storyboard. Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to support all orientations, just add the `UIRequiresFullScreen` key & set to YES on your plist.

[image]

Or just check the "Requires Full Screen" button on your Target.
[image]

Comment: If your app doesn't support multitasking, you have to set UIRequiresFullScreen even though all orientations are ticked.

Comment: what the heck is that ?! are we forced to support multitasking !? why apple is doing this when the upload process is already complex enough !